# assetEquals expects no returns but .getText returns new lines

Tags: java, selenium

assetEquals expects no returns but .getText returns new lines.  How can I make it so that .getText() doesn't return new lines?  Ive tired:

```
assertEquals("first last\n address 1\n state  zip\n Country\n email@email.com\n +353 3456546", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='mainForm']/div[2]/div")).replaceAll("\n", ""));
```

but that does not seem to work.

```
        try {
            assertEquals("first last\n address 1\n state  zip\n Country\n email@email.com\n +353 3456546", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='mainForm']/div[2]/div")).getText());
   //
        } catch (Error e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected "first last address 1 state  zip country email@email.com +353 3456546" but saw "first  last
address 1
state  zip 
country
email@email.com
+353 3456546" instead
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about `replace("\n", "");`? `replaceAll` takes regex and `\n` is a `String` literal, not regex.

Comment: replace("\n", ", "); might be better, just for readability. As written, your answer will produce "first lastaddress 1state zipcountry" and so on.